# how set color flex (html tags) position (cover all web page width, at the end of web page as footer, change relative to windows dimensions)

Tags: html, machine-learning, flexbox

1- start learning html(following free online html videos course, no css in the course).

2- use simple text edit(g edit).

3- next image show my first html code, i use flex tags to set header and footer.

4- first problem they do not cover all webpage width(point number 1 in the first image)?

5- second how set position of second flex to the end of webpage (even if it empty, no body)?

6- last problem when resize the windows, footer content align to left. how align it to center(second image show the problem)?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="imgs/iconlogo.png" alt="tab icon"/>

    
    <style>

      .flex-header {
        display: flex;
        height: 65px;
        justify-content: space-around;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #00ffc3, #bc4a4a);
      }

      .flex-header > div {
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: auto;
      }

      .white {
        color: #ffffff;
      }
    </style>

    <style>
      .flex-footer {
        display: flex;
        height: 55px;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #367b97;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .flex-footer > div {
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      .white {
        color: #ffffff;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="flex-header">
        <div><img src="imgs/logo.svg" alt="logo" width="238" height="50"></div>
        <div><span class="white">English</span></div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main>
      <p>test</p>
    </main>

    <footer>
      <div class="flex-footer">
        <div><span class="white">Copyright © 2021  Mnkjj test test test test test test test.All rights reserved</span></div>
      </div>
    </footer> 
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works.

`````
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="imgs/iconlogo.png" alt="tab icon" />


    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }

        .flex-header {
            display: flex;
            height: 65px;
            justify-content: space-around;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #00ffc3, #bc4a4a);
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }

        .flex-header>div {
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .white {
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        footer {
            margin-top: auto;
        }

        .flex-footer {
            display: flex;
            height: 55px;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: #367b97;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .flex-footer>div {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .white {
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div class="flex-header">
            <img src="imgs/logo" alt="logo">
            <span class="white">English</span>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <p>test</p>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <div class="flex-footer">
            <div><span class="white">Copyright © 2021 Mnkjj test test test test test test test.All rights
                    reserved</span></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
}````
`````

Comment: your code solve most of the problems, many thanks. but still when resize the browser windows footer content align to left(second image show the problem).
also still the flix did not cover all webpage width, maybe because i did not put it on server?

Comment: This will solve the footer problem. 

` .white { color: #ffffff; padding: 0 10px; } 
    <footer> 
        <div class="flex-footer"> 
         <span class="white">Copyright © 2021 Mnkjj test test test test test test test.All rights reserved</span> 
        </div> 
    </footer>

Answer (score 0):

solve of first problem(header and footer flex container color did not cover all webpage width), is using Margin Individual Sides:
margin-top, margin-right,
margin-bottom,
margin-left

source link:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

the final code will look like:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="imgs/iconlogo.png" alt="tab icon" />


    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }

        .flex-header {
            display: flex;
            height: 65px;
            margin-left: -15px;
            margin-right: -15px;
            margin-top: -15px;
            justify-content: space-around;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #00ffc3, #bc4a4a);
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }

        .flex-header>div {
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .white {
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        footer {
            margin-top: auto;
        }

        .flex-footer {
            display: flex;
            height: 55px;
            margin-left: -15px;
            margin-right: -15px;
            margin-bottom: -15px;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: #367b97;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .flex-footer>div {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .white {
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 0 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div class="flex-header">
            <img src="imgs/logo.svg" alt="logo">
            <span class="white">English</span>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <p>test</p>
    </main>

    <footer>
         <footer> <div class="flex-footer"> <span class="white">Copyright © 2021 Mnkjj test test test test test test test.All rights reserved</span> </div> </footer>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```